# How to stream mongo data with alpakka without any memory issue in lesser time

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka-stream, akka-http, alpakka

I'm new to alpakka. I used following code in Alpakka using MongoDB connector to fetch and loop through 100K records

```
// Using Stream
def getAllContacts(user_id: Int, list_id: Int): Source[ListContact, NotUsed] = {
        MongoSource[ListContact](mongoDB.getCollection(getCollectionName(user_id, list_id)).find())
    }
// Mongo Observable
    def getAllContacts2(user_id: Int, list_id: Int): FindObservable[ListContact] = {
        mongoDB.getCollection(getCollectionName(user_id, list_id)).find()
    }
```

Implementation:

```
def validateUserList2(user_id: Int, list_id: Int, prefix: String, filter: Option[String]): Future[Seq[PhoneNumber]] = {
    val prefixTrim = prefix.trim
    val listContact = new ListContactRepository
    listContact.getAllContacts2(user_id, list_id).map{ line =>
        validateNumber(line.phone, prefixTrim)
    }.toFuture()
}

def validateUserList(user_id: Int, list_id: Int, prefix: String, filter: Option[String]): Future[immutable.Seq[PhoneNumber]] = {
    val prefixTrim = prefix.trim
    val listContact = new ListContactRepository
    listContact.getAllContacts(user_id, list_id).runWith(Sink.seq).map(lines =>
        lines map { line =>
            validateNumber(line.phone, prefixTrim)
        }
    )
}
```

And Route:

```
// Taking around 2.5 seconds to fetch 100K data
private def mapUserListNetwork: Route = {
    get {
        path("validate" / Segment / Segment / Segment) { (userId, listId, prefix) =>
            parameters('filter.?) { filter =>
                complete((phoneValidationActor ? ValidateUserList(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix.toUpperCase, filter)).mapTo[Seq[PhoneNumber]])
            }
        }
    }
}
// Taking around 10 seconds to fetch 100K data
private def mapUserListNetwork2: Route = {
    get {
        path("validate2" / Segment / Segment / Segment) { (userId, listId, prefix) =>
            parameters('filter.?) { filter =>
                complete(PhoneNumberActor.validateUserList2(userId.toInt, listId.toInt, prefix, filter))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to stream the mongodb collection to akka-http without any Out of Memory issue/Heap Space. Please suggest the better approach.

Comment: You could also have a look at http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/streaming.html (i'm contributor of)

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of `validateUserList` instead of running (`.runWith(Sink.seq)`) the source, return it from that method. You can still apply the `map` operation there on the source.

Then `complete` the request with the `Source`. Akka Http can complete requests with sources, in which case it will take care of materialization and streaming the results to the client as a chunked response.